# C# ElasticClient v6.0.2 LowLevel.IndexAsync Creating Empty Documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Below is a portion of my code, that I've taken from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-diagnostics-tools/tree/master/AzureFunctions/EventHubsToElastic/). I had to make few changes to make work with the new v6.X of Elasticsearch.

It runs without any errors and creates new documents BUT with empty field values. If I take the same JSON payload and PUT in Elasticsearch using Postman, the document gets indexed fine, with all fields populated. Please let me know if I am using the right Elasticsearch API methods, and using them right.

```
string strJsonMessage = @"
{ 
    message : {
        content: 'Test Message Content'
    }
}";

ConnectionSettings connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("xxx")).BasicAuthentication("xx", "xx");
ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

JObject msg = JObject.Parse(strJsonMessage);
var result = await client.LowLevel.IndexAsync<BytesResponse>("events-2018.03.27", "event", PostData.Serializable(msg));

if (result.Success)
{
    log.Info("Data successfully sent.");
    log.Verbose(result.Body);
}
else
{
    log.Error("Failed to send data.");
}

****OUTPUT TRACE:****

2018-03-27T18:37:18.961 [Info] Data successfully sent.
2018-03-27T18:37:18.961 [Verbose] {"_index":"events-2018.03.27","_type":"event","_id":"u9HPaGIBBm3ZG7GB5jM_","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"_seq_no":29,"_primary_term":1}
```

Querying elasticsearch for this document by its ID gives me this:

```
{
    "_index": "events-2018.03.27",
    "_type": "event",
    "_id": "u9HPaGIBBm3ZG7GB5jM_",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "message": {
            "content": []
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes across the same issue, I got the solution [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/net-nest-elasticclient-lowlevel-indexasync-creating-document-with-empty-fields/125996).